# Spritekit - Moving Physics world issue

Tags: swift, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-kit, physics

I am building a tower stacking game. My structure is as follows:

1. I have a world node which has a physics body attached to it.
2. I add SKShapeNodes with physics bodies in it and they stack over one another.
3. When a certain height is reached, I move the worldNode down.

Now here is where the problem occurs. When I move the worldNode down, it disturbs the already placed physics bodies and it makes the tower fall quite number of times.

Coming from a Cocos2D background, I used to move the whole scene there and it did not create any problem there.

Help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of moving the world node you should move the [SKCameraNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKCameraNode/) into the opposite direction.

Comment: I think SKCameraNode was introduced in iOS 9 and i want to support old iOS versions as well.

Comment: Are you sure you want to go thru the hassle of doing this? 84% of devices run iOS9 as of May (https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/). I suggest using [SKCameraNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKCameraNode/) as well.

Comment: @Sean: I totally agree. Over a month ago iOS 8 was 11% and as soon as iOS 10 is released it will be irrelevant. It's the right time to drop iOS 8 compatibility and focus on iOS 9 and iOS 10 instead.

Comment: @appzYourLife:  Exactly! It'll be completely statistically irrelevant by September-October

Comment: @Sean: Yes, one of the best advantages we have as developers for the Apple ecosystem is that we can focus on the last 2 OS releases. Apple put a lot of effort to keep its devices updated. This means less testing cycles, less code and fewer problems to adopt new technologies.

Comment: Thank you guys. You are right. I have dropped iOS 8 compatibility and now I have used SKCameraNode and all is fine.